# show image after button is clicked in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms, postback

am trying to make an image "visible= true" after a submit button is clicked. it's an animated gif replacing the progress bar.I want it to be visible when the user first clicks. I know because of the postback it's not working. I tried using some javascript onclientclick() . I tried using the updatepanel and updateprogress still no luck.any advice on how this is done.

Comment: Quid pro quo, sir.  Quid pro quo.  (Show us what you have tried first.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will ideally need to do this using JavaScript, if you don't want the page to postback.

To do this you will need to make sure the element is on the page but hidden, so do not use the `visible="false"` property, instead use the css `display: none;` directive.

Then to show it in javascript, select it using your library of choice and show it. For example, with jquery - `$('selector').show()`

Comment: this shows the image but it's not animated. only shows the first frame. but if "display: block" is done thru css not jquery it is animated.